# Как записать в БД измененные значения?

Tags: woocommerce

Вывожу при помощи класса  нужные значения объекта WC, в поле input делаю изменения и нужно перезаписать значения.Подскажите как мне это сделать?

```
<form>
<!-- Various input fields -->
<?php
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();

foreach($delivery_zones[1]['shipping_methods'] as $zone_key=>$zone) { ?>
<label>
    <?php echo $zone->method_title ?><span>*</span>
    <input type="number" value="<?php echo $zone->cost ?>"> // In this string
</label>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $edit_action ? "Save" : "Add"; ?> Product">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<!-- Various input fields -->
<?php $delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones(); ?>

<?php foreach($delivery_zones[1]['shipping_methods'] as $zone_key=>$zone) { ?>
    <?php  $zone_title = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $zone->title));   ?>

    <label>
        <?php echo $zone->title ?><span>*</span>
        <input  id="product_shipping_method_<?php echo $zone_title ?>" type="number" name="shipping_method_<?php echo $zone_title ?>" value="<?php echo $edit_action ? get_post_meta($product_id,'_shipping_method_' . $zone_title, true) : ""; ?>"/>
    </label>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $edit_action ? "Save" : "Add"; ?> Product">
</form>
```

В файле с функционалом нужно прописать update:

```
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
    foreach($delivery_zones[2]['shipping_methods'] as $zone_key=>$zone) {
        $zone_title = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $zone->title));
        update_post_meta($product_id, '_ed_shipping_method_' . $zone_title, $_POST['shipping_method_'.$zone_title]); 
    }
```